# BufferedReader input gives unexpected result

Tags: java, input, io, bufferedreader

When I run the following code and type 50 when prompted for input:

```
    private static int nPeople;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    nPeople = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of people that will go onto the platform : ");
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        nPeople = keyboard.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(" The number of people entered --> " + nPeople);
}
```

}

I get the following output:

Please enter the amount of people that will go onto the platform : 50
 The number of people entered --> 53

Why is it returning 53 when I typed 50 ? Thanks.

Comment: What is `keyboard` and what exactly does the `read()` method do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BufferedReader#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) method reads a `single character` from your input.

So when you pass `50` as input, it just reads `5` and converts it to `ASCII` equivalent that is `53` to store it in `int` variable.

I think you need [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method here, which reads a line of text.

```
try {
    nPeople = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());  
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need `Integer.parseInt` method to convert the string representation into an `integer`.

Comment: Works thanks. However I found that using the Scanner is much easier. Any input on Scanner vs BufferedReader ?

Comment: @Jatt.. Well, if your only purpose is to read the input and print it, then `BufferedReader` is a better go. But if you want to do some `parsing` with the read input, then of course go with `Scanner` in that case.

Comment: I thought so cheers. I need to use the actual int value later on, so Scanner seems the best way. Anyways at least I know how to use BufferedReader in the future :)

Comment: @Jatt.. Yeah of course. You should know all your options. It's always good to know more to be a better programmer. Good luck and Enjoy Coding:)

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        nPeople = keyboard.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

The above code will read only the first character of your entered input.

And it was displaying the ASCII value of that character.

try using

```
 npeople = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
```

Comment: You cannot assign a String to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Because '5' is equal to 53 (ascii code)

For more details see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this :

```
private static int nPeople;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    nPeople = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of people that will go onto the platform : ");
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        String input = reader.readLine();
        nPeople =  Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(" The number of people entered --> " + nPeople);
}
```

Comment: there is no such method of Integer.parseInteger(...)